# PDF Footer for first page only

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I have an report written and working in a html. It has a footer that shows on just the every page. Can I print multiple pages exactly how I want: footer on first page, with no footer on the remaining pages.

My problem is when the report is generated as a single page. If the report is one page, there is footer fitting exactly at bottom. But, when there are more than 2-3 pages it is repeating the footer, I just want the footer appear on first page only.

Check link in comment.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "page". This is only one page. Do you mean the different sections within your page? Please be more precise!

Comment: when you `ctrl+p` it create multiple pages in print mode, i want footer on first page only,not repeating on every page. hope you understood

Comment: Ah okay, now I get it I guess. You can't do that with code. You need to comment out the footer section with `<!--  -->`. So print it the first time with the footer in it, then "hide" it with the code I posted and print it again.

Comment: When I'm trying to print your example it shows me sections from 1 to 11 + footer repeatedly on 4 pages but you have 19 sections. That's weird and I don't know why it is ignoring other sections. Maybe you should take closer look on that.

Comment: Sorry, i have updated code in pen please check: 

https://codepen.io/creativesingh/pen/BbrrLp

Comment: https://codepen.io/creativesingh/pen/BbrrLp

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate the printing outcome to vary using html. The printer does not read the code, it just prints the outcome of your code. Neither can the printer interact with your given html code to count the prints and do what you want. You need to hide the footer section with `<!--  -->` for the prints you want them not to be shown. So print it the first time with the footer in it, then "hide" it with the code I posted and print it again.

Edit:
Try it with CSS. [Demo here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first)

```
@page :first {
  //something like display:none;
 // maybe display: table-row-group; will do the trick
}
```

Comment: Its a single table, and there is only one footer `tfoot` that is repeating on every page. I just want tfoot on first page only when i go in print mode.

Comment: Css inside that will apply to first page, not to footer or table.

Comment: Sure, just give it an ID or class.